# SQLite: cast integer field value as float

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an SQL database that I'm pulling values with a WHERE clause to filter. However, I want to see if an INTEGER field value is a substring of a TEXT field value. The caveat is that I need to use wildcards.

Some sample data:

```
id    components
123   '234,345'  
234   -         
345   -
456   -
```

So I thought to use CAST(id AS TEXT) and concatenate it with '%' wildcard characters (using ||) in case the id is in the middle of the components string. But this doesn't work, i.e.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 WHERE (t1.components IS NULL OR 
(t1.components IS NOT NULL AND t1.components 
  NOT LIKE '%' || CAST(t2.id AS TEXT) || '%')) 
OR (t2.components IS NULL OR (t2.components IS NOT NULL AND t2.components 
  NOT LIKE '%' || 
CAST(t1.id AS TEXT) || '%')))
```

Should NOT return record pairs [123,234] or [123,345]

In short, how do I get `'%' || CAST(t2.id AS TEXT) || '%'` read in as `'%234%'` in my query?

Thanks!

UPDATE 9-29-2014: Ok, I figured it out. It does work. I just had a problem with my parentheses and had an OR where I should have had an AND. The new working code (though probably not optimal @deets) is:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 WHERE (t1.components IS NULL OR 
(t1.components IS NOT NULL AND t1.components 
  NOT LIKE '%' || CAST(t2.id AS TEXT) || '%')) 
AND (t2.components IS NULL OR (t2.components IS NOT NULL AND t2.components 
  NOT LIKE '%' || CAST(t1.id AS TEXT) || '%')))
```

Comment: I think what you are doing here is not really the right way to go about your problem. You try to represent a 1:n  or n:m relationship in a text-field. Use a proper relational table instead.

Comment: On a related note: it works in principle for me. So I guess your issue is in the overall structure of your data & query, not the actual attempt at constructing a match-pattern. On top of that, you do not account for submatches: 123 is contained in 12345. So to make your approach work (which you shouldn't use in the first place), you'd have to actually use a pattern '%,<id>,%', and of course ensure you surround your data with commas.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Then what is the best way to structure this data to make this robust if some ids have 0 or more component ids?

Comment: As I said, a simple new table would be all you need. E.g. "create table components_to_subcomponents ( parent int, child int)" with values [(123, 234), (123, 345)] would be the canonical way of modelling this.